# How to resolve the promise call soon in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

on click of search button api will be triggered where there is delay in getting response because of which router navigation is not happening immediately.

I need to reduce this delay so how to achieve this?

sample code:

```
 restfulService.search($stateParams.keyword, $stateParams.facets, customFilterQuery).then (function (searchResult) {});
```

delay in getting searchresult.

Comment: ... if you're making an API request, for sure there will be delay and that is a matter of the user connection and the API latency itself? you could navigate to the route and place a loader while waiting for the API response...

Comment: here case is on delete of last item from cart page should route to search page .but before routing update api wil be triggered where page is shown with empty feild details..so that much delay is there.even when spinner will be loading empty details are shown ince update call gets completed and then route happens.

Comment: before update calls gets completed routing should happen.